# Search for start of string in sql query and return entire string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to search for a string in SQL by searching for the first few chars which I know will be unique and return the string right up to the first space after it.

However it is not returning what I expect. Here is my statement:

```
declare @searchString varchar(max),
        @searchForStartChars varchar(max)

set @searchString = 'My ST_Test001 testing blah'
set @searchForStartChars = 'ST_Test'

select SUBSTRING(@searchString,
        charindex(@searchForStartChars,@searchString,1),
            charindex(' ',@searchString,
                charindex(@searchForStartChars,@searchString,1)))
```

I want this to return ST_Test001

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution (since I put the time into it already, lol):

```
DECLARE @searchString VARCHAR(MAX),
        @searchForStartChars VARCHAR(MAX),
        @searchStringStartPos INTEGER;

SET @searchString = 'My ST_Test001 testing blah';
SET @searchForStartChars = 'ST_Test';
SET @searchStringStartPos = CHARINDEX(@searchForStartChars, @searchString, 1) 

SELECT      CASE
                WHEN @searchStringStartPos = 0 THEN ''
                ELSE    CASE
                            WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@searchString, @searchStringStartPos, LEN(@searchString)), 1) = 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@searchString, @searchStringStartPos, LEN(@searchString))
                            ELSE SUBSTRING(@searchString, @searchStringStartPos, CHARINDEX(' ', SUBSTRING(@searchString, @searchStringStartPos, LEN(@searchString)), 1) - 1)
                        END
            END AS EntireSearchString;
```

Comment: Fair enough! Better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't substract the starting point of the first match from the length in the `substring`:

```
declare @searchString varchar(max),
        @searchForStartChars varchar(max)

set @searchString = 'My ST_Test001 testing blah'
set @searchForStartChars = 'ST_Test'

select SUBSTRING( @searchString
                , charindex( @searchForStartChars, @searchString, 1 )
                , charindex( ' '
                           , @searchString
                           , charindex( @searchForStartChars, @searchString, 1 )
                           )
                   - charindex( @searchForStartChars, @searchString, 1 )
                )
```

I added this after the current code in the last parameter of `substring`:

```
- charindex( @searchForStartChars, @searchString, 1 )
```

Comment: @realtek: Just to let you know, this code will break if the substring you are looking for has no spaces after it, like if it is the last part of the string (including if it is just the entire string itself).  Cool if it's not a concern for you.

Comment: Thanks VBlades, very good point... Yes I will have to use your version to get around that. Well spotted. Thanks